# Angular 4 - HTTP Interceptor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create HTTP Interceptor in Angular 4 but I'm having some weird error. Following is my error:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

Following is my Code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options)); // Here is the error
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, options)); // Here is the error
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))); // Here is the error
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))); // Here is the error
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options)); // Here is the error
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers(); // Here is the error
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status == 401 && !_.endsWith(err.url, 'api/auth/login')) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? I tried debugging for 3 hours but unable to find any clue.

**Edit:**

I also tried to remove everything and written a code like this:

```js
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options);
}
```

But still it's giving same error:

`Argument of type 'string | Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Request'. Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'string | Request'.`

Comment: that's because Observable.empty() isn't an Observable<Response>.

Comment: Ok I just tried to remove everything and written just:

`request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options);
    }`

But still it's giving same error:

`Argument of type 'string | Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Request'.
  Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'string | Request'.`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Http interceptor is already implemented in Angular 4.3.4 and is described in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses).

You need to implement the `intercept` method of `HttpInterceptor` interface, do something with the request, and call the `next.handle(req)` method.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const changedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('My-Header', 'MyHeaderValue')});
    return next.handle(changedReq);
  }
}
```

It's also necessary to register interceptor in app's providers section

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: NoopInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you have to use HttpClient service instead of Http service. https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient

Comment: Could it be it never intercepts OPTIONS requests?

Comment: @Stefan you can check the request method and call next.handle if it's OPTIONS. `if (req.method==='OPTIONS') `

Comment: new link is [Intercepting Requests and Responces](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Answer (score 17):

akn's answer is the right one. I was trying to make it work with **http** service, but the interceptor only works whit **httpClient** service.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

The globally available DOM typings (`"lib": ["dom"]` in your tsconfig) include `Response` and `Request` interfaces that are unrelated to the types used by Angular.

You need to import `Response` and `Request` from `@angular/http`.

Comment: I'm also facing same problem like Sahil, i'm not sure how to add with in "tsconfig.json" below is my file

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"      
    ]
  }
}

Comment: You shouldn't have to touch tsconfig.json.

Comment: @Velkumar I just imported Response and Request in my imports. It solved my problem.

Comment: You may look at this post, might help with explaining the details: https://modewagon.wordpress.com/2017/09/13/angular-4-http-interceptor/

Answer (score 3):

The following instruction worked for me perfectly:

In the app module:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { myInterceptor} from './Interceptors/myInterceptor';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
...
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MyInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

In the interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // when there is POST request
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      const req= req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', content_type),
        body: 'my body'
      });

      return next.handle(accessReq);
    }
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: http should be an instance of HttpClient!

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, private accessTokenService: AccessTokenService
) { }
    return this.http.post(ingestURL, null)
        .map(res => {
            return res; // data returned from interceptor
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic to intercept Ajax in any framework.

```
private bootstrapAjaxInterceptor() {
const _self = this;
const originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (xhrMethod, requestUrl) {
  this.addEventListener('readystatechange', xhr => {
    switch (this.readyState) {
      case 1: _self.onAjaxStart(xhrMethod, requestUrl); break;
      case 4: _self.onAjaxStop(this.responseURL, this.response); break;
      default: // Nothing to handle here
    }
  }, false);
  originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

}

Here is complete example for Angular.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
interface AjaxRequest {
  url?: string;
  requestCount?: number;
  method?: string;
}
interface AjaxResponse {
  url?: string;
  requestCount?: number;
  response?: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor {
  public ajaxStart = new BehaviorSubject<AjaxRequest>({});
  public ajaxStop = new BehaviorSubject<AjaxResponse>({});
  private requestQueue: Array<any> = [];
  constructor() {
    this.bootstrapAjaxInterceptor();
  }
  public getRequestQueue() {
    return this.requestQueue;
  }
  private bootstrapAjaxInterceptor() {
    const _self = this;
    const originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (xhrMethod, requestUrl) {
      this.addEventListener('readystatechange', xhr => {
        switch (this.readyState) {
          case 1: _self.onAjaxStart(xhrMethod, requestUrl); break;
          case 4: _self.onAjaxStop(this.responseURL, this.response); break;
          default: // Nothing to handle here
        }
      }, false);
      originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }
  onAjaxStart(xhrMethod, requestUrl) {
    this.requestQueue.push(requestUrl.replace(/\?.*/, ''));
    this.ajaxStart.next({
      url: requestUrl,
      requestCount: this.requestQueue.length,
      method: xhrMethod
    });
  }
  onAjaxStop(responseURL, response) {
    const responseUrl = responseURL.split(/\?/)[0];
    this.requestQueue.forEach((urlEndpoint, i) => {
      if (new RegExp(`${urlEndpoint}$`).test(responseUrl)) {
        return this.requestQueue.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
    this.ajaxStop.next({
      url: responseUrl,
      requestCount: this.requestQueue.length,
      response: response
    });
  }
}
```