# How to retrieve data from an Observable and use it in an Interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building the front-end of an application in `Angular 8`. This application uses an `OAuth 2` implementation to manage authentication (password grant) so any `HTTP` request (with the exception of ones to the token endpoint) needs to have on its header a valid access_token.

To provide said token I've made an `Angular interceptor` that retrieve the token from another service and then attach it to the intercepted `HTTP` request. The token retrieval method doesn't give directly the token but an observable which eventually resolves to a valid token, I made this choice because the access token may not be instantly available, if the token is expired the application needs to refresh it with an `HTTP` call and then the refreshed token can be passed to the `HTTP` interceptor.

The problem which I encounter is that despite my many attempts the interceptor doesn't wait for the token to be retrieved so at the end the interceptor is skipped and the `HTTP` request is made without any token attached.

This is the code of my interceptor, `retrieveValidToken` is the `Observable` which returns the token.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FacadeService } from './facade.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private facadeService: FacadeService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.includes('localhost:3000') && !req.url.endsWith('token')) {
      this.facadeService.retrieveValidToken()
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {
            const clone = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res}` } });
            return next.handle(clone);
          },
          (err) => {
            const clone = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ` } });
            return next.handle(clone);
          }
        );
    } else {
    return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables are asynchronous. The code outside the subscribe method will not wait for the code inside.

You should return observable by itself, not only result inside its subscription:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.includes('localhost:3000') && !req.url.endsWith('token')) {
      return this.facadeService.retrieveValidToken()
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            const clone = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res}` } });
            return next.handle(clone);
          }
        );
    } else {
    return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```

Something similar:

[How use async service into angular httpClient interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345354/how-use-async-service-into-angular-httpclient-interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'intercept' method should return observable immediately, so instead of subscribing to 'this.facadeService.retrieveValidToken()' use the following code:

`return this.facadeService.retrieveValidToken().pipe(
    mergeMap(token => 
        next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}' }))
    )
)`