# Async/wait Uncaught (in promise) when exception

Tags: angular, async-await

I have my service signUp

```
async signUp(credentials: ICreateCredentials) {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signUp({
        username : credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
        attributes: {
          email: credentials.email,
          phone_number: ''
        }
      });

      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" sign up error ");
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

This service is called in my register.component.ts file

```
  async onSubmit() {
    if (!this.registerForm.valid || this.buttonDisabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.buttonDisabled = true;
    this.buttonState = 'show-spinner';

    try {
      const user = this.authService.signUp(this.registerForm.value);
      console.log({ user });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(' ooook');
      // The registration failed
      this.notifications.create(
        'Error',
        error.message,
        NotificationType.Bare,
        { theClass: 'outline primary', timeOut: 6000, showProgressBar: false }
      );
      this.buttonDisabled = false;
      this.buttonState = '';
    }  

  }
```

When Auth.signUp function raise an error, i can see "sign up error" then the stack trace in my browser, I never enter inside the catch of submit to handle it correctly in a pop up.

I get the message error in my browser:

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Object:
>   {"code":"UsernameExistsException","name":"UsernameExistsException",
>   "message":"An account with the given email already exists."}"

What is wrong with my code ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your service return observable?

Comment: @AdamNorman no, because I use async, the service return a promise, but according to the documentation, I can use try/catch

Comment: could you strongly type the expected return of you function async signUp(credentials: ICreateCredentials) : Promise<T>{

Comment: When i strongly type as suggested I get the error : error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

Comment: replace T with the User Type or set It To any

Comment: even if I add Promise<any> I still get the initial error ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"code":"UsernameExistsException","name":"UsernameExistsException", "message":"An account with the given email already exists."}"

Comment: then Could you use interceptor look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345354/how-use-async-service-into-angular-httpclient-interceptor