# Angular 12 HttpInterceptor Wait until a http client method finish

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, jwt, interceptor

Hi I am trying to check when a token is about to expire and reload it with the access token.
The main problem is that to reload it I have to make a http call to get the new token and then I will re save it in the session storage.
The main problem is that because the http is async it reloads the token, but because I dont know how to wait until this call is finish to retry the original call with the new token it fail.

This is the code:

AuthService:
This is the service that is being called to update the token

```js
async reloadIdTokenFromAccess(accessToken : string | null) {
  console.log("Performing call to reload token");
  const resp = await this.httpClient.post<IdTokenDTO>(`${environment.backendUrl}/auth/tokenReload`,accessToken).toPromise();
  this.setIdToken(resp.idToken);
  this.setExpireAt(resp.expireAt);
  console.log("Data update in session storage")
}
```

interceptor

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authServ : AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

    let token: string | null = this.authServ.getIdToken();
    let expiration: number | null = this.authServ.getExpireAt();
    let reloaded : boolean = false;

    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    if(expiration != null && !request.url.includes("tokenReload") && !request.url.includes("login")){
      if(expiration <= currentTime + 60000 && this.authServ.getAccessToken() != null){
        reloaded = true;
        console.log("Token expiration Time near to expire, reloading token")
        this.authServ.reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken());
        token = this.authServ.getIdToken();
        console.log("Finish all full reloading")
      }
    }

    if(reloaded){
      console.log("Starting the request with the new token")
    }

    let originalReq = request;

    if(token){
      request = originalReq.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${ token }`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

If I check the logs I see the following:
[image]

As you can check the request is being performen before the token is reloaded.
How can i force this request to be finish before continue with the method?

Just something similar like in java a CompletableFuture with the get() method to block the code until it finish

I also have test things like this without success

```js
async reloadIdTokenFromAccess(accessToken : string | null) {
  console.log("Performing call to reload token");
  await this.httpClient.post<IdTokenDTO>(`${environment.backendUrl}/auth/tokenReload`,accessToken).subscribe( (resp : IdTokenDTO) => {
    this.setIdToken(resp.idToken);
    this.setExpireAt(resp.expireAt);
    console.log("updates token in session storage")
  })
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authServ : AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return from(this.handle(request, next));
  }

  async handle(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const expiration: number | null = this.authServ.getExpireAt();
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    let reloaded: boolean = false;

    if (expiration != null && !request.url.includes('tokenReload') &&!request.url.includes('login')) {
      if (expiration <= currentTime + 60000 && this.authServ.getAccessToken() != null) {
        reloaded = true;
        console.log('Token expiration Time near to expire, reloading token');
        await this.authServ.reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken());
        console.log('Finish of call reaload token');
      }
    }

    const token = this.authServ.getIdToken();

    if (reloaded){ 
      console.log('Starting the request with the new token');
    }

    const originalReq = request;

    if (token) {
      request = originalReq.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).toPromise();

  }
}
```

I am desesperate. dont know what to do (maybe continue studing courses and tutorials but i have dedlines) :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you should await your promises inside the interceptor?

Comment: You never wait on the promise to finish when calling it on line `this.authServ.reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken());` You must use `then` or `async/await`. Honestly though I would try to keep this all consistent and use either RxJs for everything in the stack or use Promise. My preference would be RxJs.

Comment: @Igor can you explain it better, I am a bit novice and actually my problem is that I dont know how to make the code to wait until the promisse finish

Comment: what does `this.authServ.reloadIdTokenFromAccess` return? is it a observable or promise?

Answer (score 1):

In your `authService`, return the http response using `Observables`

```js
reloadIdTokenFromAccess(accessToken : string | null): Observable<IdTokenDTO> {
    console.log("Performing call to reload token");
    return this.httpClient.post<IdTokenDTO>(`${environment.backendUrl}/auth/tokenReload`,accessToken);
}
```

And, in your interceptor, you would proceed like this:

```js
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const expiration: number | null = this.authServ.getExpireAt();
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    let reloaded: boolean = false;

    if (
      expiration != null &&
      !request.url.includes('tokenReload') &&
      !request.url.includes('login')
    ) {
      if (
        expiration <= currentTime + 60000 &&
        this.authServ.getAccessToken() != null
      ) {
        reloaded = true;
        console.log('Token expiration Time near to expire, reloading token');

        // unwrap your response from the observable
        this.authServ
          .reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken())
          .pipe(
            tap((response: any) => {
              this.authServ.setIdToken(response.idToken);
              this.authServ.setExpireAt(response.expireAt);
              console.log('Data update in session storage');
            })
          )
          .subscribe(() => this.addToken(request, reloaded));
      }
    }

    const req = this.addToken(request, reloaded);
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, reloaded: boolean) {
    const token = this.authServ.getIdToken();
    console.log('Finish all full reloading');

    if (reloaded) console.log('Starting the request with the new token');

    const originalReq = request;

    if (token) {
      request = originalReq.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
    }

    return request;
  }
```

Comment: Yes but If put everithing within the subscription I ommit the part of adding the Bearer token for the rest of request when the token dont have to be reloaded....I mean,
This part must be done always : let originalReq = request;

            if (token) {
              request = originalReq.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
              });
            }

Comment: I have more request that go thorugh this interceptor to set the token. I have change the code and test your solution and nothing works because the rest of the request when it is not needed to reaload the token fails because the token in not being iyected by the interceptor

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido, I have edited my answer, let me know if it is working for you

Comment: I am sorry but it does not work, it makes a first call before updating the token and I get an unathorized :(. It is not waiting until the Observable is finish

Answer (score 1):

You should use higher-order observables. Here's a nice read
https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/higher-order-observable/

Try doing the following:

```
reloadIdTokenFromAccess(accessToken : string | null) : Observable<IdTokenDTO> {
    console.log("Performing call to reload token");
    return this.httpClient.post<IdTokenDTO>(`${environment.backendUrl}/auth/tokenReload`,accessToken)
      .tap( (resp : IdTokenDTO) => {
        this.setIdToken(resp.idToken);
        this.setExpireAt(resp.expireAt);
        console.log("updates token in session storage")
      });
  }
```

`tap` will just intercept and save the token everytime you reload and it will return the observable which can then be combined with another observable.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authServ : AuthService) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const expiration: number | null = this.authServ.getExpireAt();
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    let reloaded: boolean = false;

    if (expiration != null && !request.url.includes('tokenReload') &&!request.url.includes('login')) {
      if (expiration <= currentTime + 60000 && this.authServ.getAccessToken() != null) {

        console.log('Token expiration Time near to expire, reloading token');

        return this.reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken()).pipe(
          concatMap(token => {
            request = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }
            });
            return next.handle(request);
          })
        )

        console.log('Finish of call reaload token');
      }
    }
    
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

`concatMap` will wait for the previous HTTP Observable to complete before mapping the new value to an HTTP Observable

Answer (score 0):

I am finally using a timer that every X minutes check the token. Silent reload.
I put this timer in the main component of the application and thats it.

Thanks anyway.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
...
public subscription : Subscription;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = timer(0, (300 *1000)).pipe().subscribe(() => {
      //console.log("ejecutando recarga del token");
      const expiration: number | null = this.authServ.getExpireAt();
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

      let reloaded: boolean = false;

      if (expiration != null) {
        if (expiration <= currentTime + (350 * 1000) && this.authServ.getAccessToken() != null) {
          reloaded = true;
          //console.log('Token expiration Time near to expire, reloading token');
          this.authServ.reloadIdTokenFromAccess(this.authServ.getAccessToken());
        }
      }
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```