# How do I make intercept function in Interceptor waits a Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to make `intercept` function waits for `Promise` to be resolved before each `API` call to check user if still active or not , if he is active I'll perform his request other wise I'll `return EMPTY;`(Prevent him from editing and logout) like this

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private userChecker: UserChecker
  ) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

// custom code for headers 

let x = this.userChecker.getUserStatus(); // this function call API and will return a promise that resolve boolean true if he is still active and false if not 

/* try 1
x.then((resolve) => {
   if (!resolve) {
     // logut 
   }else return next.handle(request);
});
*/

/*try 2
if(userChecker.shouldLogout){
// logout
}else return next.handle(request);
*/

//this is the normal state without any try of above
return next.handle(request);


}
```

**At Try1 :**
will continue execution without returning anything either if it resolve true or false

**At Try2 :**
will continue before `shouldLogout` modified in API subscription

How do I prevent `intercept` from continue execution until I receive the flag from the `API`  to continue or logout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use async service into angular httpClient interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345354/how-use-async-service-into-angular-httpclient-interceptor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your promise to an `Observable` instead with [`from`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from). Then use [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) to prevent the request from happening unless the `shouldLogout` flag is set to false:

```js
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return from(this.userChecker.getUserStatus()).pipe(
  filter(() => !this.userChecker.shouldLogout),
  mergeMap(() => next.handle(request))
);
```