# Angular - Waiting for refresh token function to finish before forwarding the request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jwt, interceptor

I'm working on an auth system in angular with a django backend with jwt. I have an angular interceptor which checks within every request if the access token is still valid and if not, it calls a refreshtoken function and refreshes the access token.

Here is the code of the interceptor:

```js
constructor(private authService:AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    
    if(access_token){
      // Check if access token is no longer valid, if so, refresh it with the refresh token
      if(this.authService.isLoggedOut()){
        
        this.authService.refreshToken();
        access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      }
      const cloned = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
      });
      return next.handle(cloned);
    } 
    else{
      return next.handle(request);
    }
```

It gets the access_token and checks the validity with the help of the auth service.
My problem is that if its unvalid its calls the refreshToken() function which looks like this,

```js
  refreshToken(){
    let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
    console.log("BEFORE REFRESH: " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
 
    return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}token/refresh/`, {"refresh" : refresh_token}).subscribe(res => {
      let access_token = res["access"]
      const expiresAt = this.tokenExpiresAt(access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));

      console.log("AFTER REFRESH: " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
    });
  }
```

but it doesn't wait for the refresh token function to finish and returns the handle.
So the first request with an invalid token throws an error and only the next requests are fine.

How can I revise this to wait for refreshToken() to finish?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345354/how-use-async-service-into-angular-httpclient-interceptor

So you can basically wait for your auth response and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined the answers from multiple questions and finally came up with this solution:

Interceptor:

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  
    if (access_token) {
      // Check if access token is no longer valid, if so, refresh it with the refresh token
      if (this.authService.isLoggedOut()) {
        return from(this.authService.refreshToken()).pipe(
          mergeMap((access_token) => {
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
            const cloned = request.clone({
              headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token),
            });
            return next.handle(cloned);
          })
        );
      }
      const cloned = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token),
      });
      return next.handle(cloned);
    } else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
```

refreshToken:

```js
async refreshToken(): Promise<string> {
    let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token"); 
    const res$ = this.http
    .post(`${apiUrl}token/refresh/`, { refresh: refresh_token })
    .pipe(map((res) => res["access"]))
    .pipe(first());
    const res = await lastValueFrom(res$);

    const expiresAt = this.tokenExpiresAt(res);
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", res);
    localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
    console.log("Refreshed Access Token");
    return res;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rxjs` operators such as `switchMap`

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if (access_token) {
        // Check if access token is no longer valid, if so, refresh it with the refresh token
        if (this.authService.isLoggedOut()) {
            return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
                switchMap(token => {
                    const cloned = request.clone({
                        headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                    });
                    return next.handle(cloned);
                })
            )
        }
    } else {
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

and in `refreshToken` function - make it return `Observsble` and set the `localStorage` inside `pipe`

```
refreshToken(){
let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
console.log("BEFORE REFRESH: " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));

return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}token/refresh/`, {"refresh" : refresh_token}).pipe(tap(res => {
  let access_token = res["access"]
  const expiresAt = this.tokenExpiresAt(access_token);
  localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
  localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));

  console.log("AFTER REFRESH: " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
});
 )
 }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! I think I get the idea but sadly it gives me an "ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ... " error

Comment: I tried to debug it and it seems like it crashes inside of the refreshtoken function but I'm not really sure

Comment: There's two if conditions. Make sure you return value in all cases, because this function must return value (as the error you get.)