# Angular 4 Using HttpInterceptor to bind header at runtime

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular4-httpclient

PPl here marking it duplicate rather reading this question...
The link is how to add interceptor...that I am doing already and have posted code already, question is modifying headers to be sent in interceptor

Flow of application -

Login page - user logs in- gets a token and then in all http requests need to send that token.

Working sceario

```
   var headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('X-Token', '123'); <-- read token from storage
return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, {headers: this.headers});
```

but problem is I have to read that token everytime which is not needed, so I cahnged code to extend HttpInterceptor

```
export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Clone the request to add the new header
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('X-Token', 'a') });

    // Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
```

But question is does anyone know, how can I add that token at runtime, basically after user logs in  and get that token , I need to update token in that interceptor.

Comment: Not at all possible. The link is how to add interceptor...that I am doing already and have posted code above, question is modifying headers to be send in interceptor

Comment: You can store the token into service and inject that service into HttpInterceptor. Whenever token updates service will provide you the updated token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - HTTP Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396890/angular-4-http-interceptor)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the problem is here. If you have the token stored somewhere, why not then fetch it in your interceptor?