# Web tokens in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, jwt

I am sending a POST request to a back end REST API, via a login component. I get an x-auth token back in the response headers.
How do I get and store this token so I can use it for all other API requests for the duration of the users logged in session?
Cheers

Comment: A cookie, session storage, local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.access_token);
```

This is how I did it with Angular 5:

My LoginService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpService } from '../services/http.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
    }

    login(user: string, pass: string) {
        const params = new HttpParams()
            .append('grant_type', 'password')
            .append('username', user)
            .append('password', pass);
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post('login', params, { headers: headers });
    }
}
```

My Login Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginService } from '../../services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    public pageTitle = 'User login';
    errorMessage = '';
    loginFormGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private _loginService: LoginService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formBuild();
    }

    formBuild() {
        this.loginFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            loginUser: ['', [Validators.required]],
            loginPass: ['', [Validators.required]],
        });
    }

    onLogin() {
        let response: any;
        this._loginService.login(this.loginFormGroup.value.loginUser, this.loginFormGroup.value.loginPass)
            .subscribe(
                response => { response= response; },
                error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; },
                () => {

                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.access_token);
                });
    }
}
```

I keep my token in localeStorage.

I have created interceptors for usage of this token:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}

export const TokenInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

This solution fro Angular 5 and HTTPClient. If you need solution for only Angular 2 let me know, I will post that to you.

Comment: Nice one. Thankyou very much for the solution, much appreciated

Comment: It was my pleasure to help. Will you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Store the token you are receiving in the local storage of the web browser and use an http interceptor to remove the token from all responses and add the token to all requests.

Comment: can you tell me how to use it for interceptor ?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396890/angular-4-http-interceptor

Answer (score 1):

Using `NgCookie` module you may set like:

```
  $cookies.put("token","your_response_val");
```

After that for further use.... `$cookies.get ()`

Comment: the convention is rather use local\session storage. among other advantages, it wipes out the risk of `XSRF`

Comment: @Stavm sessions aren't persistent and localstorage isn't fully adopted. You can store tokens in a Cookie just fine as long as you're using the httponly flag.