# how do i read basic authentication token on login for the first time?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: this is the login api result- header in postman]

this is angular code to retrieve token in console

```
  return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, bodystr, this._requestOption)
        .subscribe(response => {
          if(response.headers.has("authorization"))
          {
              let token = response.headers.get("authorization");

              console.log(token);
          }
          console.log("cookie: " + response.headers.get("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: authorization"));
          console.log(response.headers.get("Authorization"));
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }, err => {
            throw err;
        });
  }
```

and i am unable to access the token from the header.

Comment: Make sure your backend sends the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header with a value of `Authorization` so that the browser allows it to be read

Comment: So, what do those console.logs show?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960671/web-tokens-in-angular-2/48962144#48962144) for one of my solutions on how to implement token authorization. Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "Authorization")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
        string AuthenticationTokken = Common.GetToken(user.UserName,user.Password);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        response.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+ AuthenticationTokken);

        return response;
    }
```