# oidc-client angular 6 Token lost after F5

Tags: angular, authentication, refresh, angular6, openid-connect

When I login then Get token successfully. and also i navigate from one page to another page then also token remain. But when I press F5 (refresh) token or userData lost. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to save your token and userData in some variable or in a localstorage. That way it will not be lost after refresh. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960671/web-tokens-in-angular-2/48962144#48962144) for example.