# HttpClient Request intercepter like, at time of getting response from server

Tags: angular, httpclient, intercept

I want to open a loader popup when request is trying to hit and after getting response,I want to close it.
Is any way with using httpclient to perform it from a single place.

Comment: You could implement an HTTP interceptor... `https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor`

Comment: @Guntram I want to use it when the response came from server end. Before send a service we can use intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler)

Comment: You do not provide any code, example what you did, or jsfiddle (or similar), what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396890/angular-4-http-interceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class I1 implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public service: SomeService) {
    console.log(service);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.service.loading = true;
    });

    return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.service.loading = false;
          });

        }
      },
      (err: any) => {

      }
    );
  }
}
```

**SomeService.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  _loading = false;
  constructor() {

  }

  set loading(isLoad: boolean) {
    this._loading = isLoad;
  }

  get loading() {
    return this._loading;
  }

}
```

And in your `Root` component inject this service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        IsLoading: {{service.loading}}
        <div><h3>Response</h3>{{response|async|json}}</div>
        <button (click)="request()">Make request</button>`
    ,
})
export class AppComponent {
    response: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, public service: SomeService) {}

    request() {
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
        this.response = this.http.get(url, {observe: 'body'});
    }
}
```

[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-8zh9th)

2. With using **BehaviorSubject**

**SpinnerService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private visible$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  show() {
    this.visible$.next(true);
  }

  hide() {
    this.visible$.next(false);
  }

  isVisible(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.visible$.asObservable().pipe(share());
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz EXAMPLE](https://angular-interceptors-loading.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Nice, I got it with tap and finally there.

Comment: @mukundpatel, updated answer: added it by using spinner and `BehaviorSubject`