# Setting a global Angular variable from within HTML Template

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

I have a spinner component in my main `AppComponent` as follows: `template: <app-spinner></app-spinner>`. Here's the spinner component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="spinner.isVisible() | async" class="spinner">
      <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
  constructor(public spinner: SpinnerService) {}
}
```

And here's the spinner service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private visible$ = new BehaviorSubject < boolean > (false);

  show() {
    this.visible$.next(true);
  }

  hide() {
    this.visible$.next(false);
  }

  isVisible(): Observable < boolean > {
    return this.visible$.asObservable().pipe(share());
  }
}
```

I can easily show the spinner from any component by injecting `SpinnerService` and invoking `show()`... but then I'd like to also be able to do the following in any component:

```js
<div *ngIf="userObservable | async as user; else loading">
  Hello {{user.name}}!
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Somehow do something here to set the spinner visibility and switch it off later?!</ng-template>
```

I'm also very open to using a global injected variable instead of a `Subject`. Any ideas?

**Hint**: Can we maybe define something like a "global [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)" somehow?!

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you want to show the spinner during a loading process, like a network call. If that's the case, you can set a boolean variable in your component `showSpinner`, initially set to `true`, make your call in your `ngOnInit` (or where you need it) and set `showSpinner` to `false` in the subscribe, when you get the result from the network call.

You can use that variable in an `*ngIf` in your HTML to display the spinner only when necessary.

Comment: Thank you, that's already what I'm doing; but my question was about avoiding setting `showSpinner` to anything and using `*ngIf`'s `else` block instead to make the `app-spinner` in `AppComponent` visible.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
<div *ngIf="userObservable | async as user; else loading">
  Hello {{user.name}}!
</div>
<ng-template #loading> <div class="loading"></div></ng-template>
```

> My request is to have the top-most component (app-spinner) "get
>   activated" somehow

The scope of a `reference variable(#var)` is the entire template.
It means you can access in only in the current template. You can't get `#variable` from any other template contexts(another components...)

[Use Angular template reference variables anywhere in the template... not!](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html)

You can also look this [[answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49513866/5677886). 
It solves loading in global state by using `Interceptor`

Comment: I don't get it. My request is to have the top-most component (`app-spinner`) "get activated" somehow.

Comment: Still not :(
I hope this could demonstrate what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/znnyo0vrol

Comment: @Sammy, I understand your problem. But I think it's not possible what you ask. If you don't want to inject `SpinnerService` in component, another approach is injecting it to `Interceptor`. With `Interceptor` loading process is handled globally  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-loading