# HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is not getting called using angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I want to implement loader on every request start and hide the loader on the request finish, I have implemented the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('event--->>>', event);                }
                return event;
            }));
    }
}
```

and i have registered the HTTP_INTERCEPTOR in **app.module.ts** like this

```
 providers: [ 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor, multi: true}
  ]
```

but when I make a HTTP call the **intercept method** is not getting called, do I have to add anything else apart from this?
I have followed this [blog](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/) but I am not able to handle it

the intercept method is getting initiated, but when the response or request is made the appropriate method is not getting called.

> for instance

when I get a response I would want the

```
if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('event--->>>', event);                }
                return event;
            }
```

to get executed

Comment: make sure you have imported the HttpClient module in the same app.module.ts

Comment: yes, i have imported httpClientModule

Comment: do i have to hook this interceptor class to my http request making class?

Comment: no, that is not needed. Are you using `HttpClient` service to send requests or `Http` service. if you are using `Http` service you will need to replace all calls with `HttpClient`.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396890/angular-4-http-interceptor/45760443#45760443